# Eliminating scientific notation on vertical axis of 3d plot (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, mplot3d, z-axis

How can I eliminate the scientific notation on the vertical axis of a 3d plot, and replace it with integers? e.g., instead of `0.0+2.002e3`, I would like `2002` My sample script is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

yearvec = [2002, 2003, 2004]
plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_zlim3d(yearvec[0], yearvec[-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html) and [`ax.zaxis.set_major_locator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter, MultipleLocator

yearvec = [2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 250)
ax.set_zlim3d(yearvec[0], yearvec[-1])

majorLocator   = MultipleLocator(1)
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
zFormatter = FormatStrFormatter('%d')
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(zFormatter)
```

This is what you want?
[image]

Comment: Perfect! That's precisely what I'm looking for. Thank you!